# Transfer iPhone 5 photo library on to a Network Storage Device

Tags: iphone, wifi, nas

I'm running out of space on my iPhone and would like to transfer my iPhone photos to a NAS and then delete them. I like to view my pictures from NAS via an app.

Can somebody recommend a good NAS and app that can help me achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a local solution for your media, you could consider using [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/?vm=r&s=1). With [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/?vm=r&s=1) you can stream videos, photos, and even use it for storage. You get roughly 2 GB for free (more if you refer users), but if you need more space you can easily upgrade your account, for a fee, to the Pro version which provides much more storage.

Answer (score -1):

Synology NAS hardware offers this, take a look to the apps[1] I think it is what you are looking for.

[1] Photo Station is the app: https://www.synology.com/en-global/dsm/5.2/multimedia

Comment: Could you offer a link to an app that satisfies the OP's needs?

Comment: Added some links...